# Ogone payment error integration with Android

Tags: android, payment-gateway, payment-processing

I integrated Ogone Payment library for Android in my app. When I trying to validate a test payment (with credit card number 4111111111111111) I always receive the following error :

```
unknown order/1/4525af54488855sd555c4f84dd455
```

I contacted the technical support, they told me the parameters provided are not correct. But I don't see where is the problem !

Anyone can help me to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a IP problem you must go in your ogone account and your technical settings -> data and origin verfication and you must set one or more IP adress. If the ip address of device or server not correspond you are this error message.